# "Checkbox" does not work correctly

Tags: angular

There is an "is_active" field in the database. This field has a Varchar1 data type set. Where true is "Y" and false is "N". So when adding new if "checkbox" is active set to "N", and if not active then a null value. How can I fix it so that if the active check box is set to "Y" and not active "N".

```
<input type="checkbox" id="is_active" name="is_active" #is_active='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="project.is_active" [checked]="project.is_active == 'Y'" />
```

Comment: What is printed in console for `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @LahiruChandima Simply displays all the information so in the console is_active: false

Comment: Then there should be an issue with your service or the backend where 'Y' is taken as `false`

Comment: @LahiruChandima Yes, it's unlikely, if you just output information, everything works fine, but if you add a new one, then there is no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `change` event of the input to set the correct value to `project.is_active`.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="is_active" name="is_active" [checked]="project.is_active== 'Y'" (change)="onIsActiveChanged($event)" />


public onIsActiveChanged(event: any) {
  this.project.is_active = event.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```

Comment: Not helped me this(

Comment: @user10091508 there was a mistake in the answer and I corrected it. Check again. If it still fails, add a `console.log(this.project)` just before you save the data and check whether `project` object contains the correct value.

Comment: why doesn't it work after saving the data? Before saving: is_active
:
"Y". After saving:  is_active
:
"false"

Comment: @user10091508 please post the code you use to save.

Comment: Thank you, it  helped me I found a mistake))